# Why is my rust slower than my C - memory manipulation?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, rust

I have two implmentations that yield the same `Vec` in the end, however my C implementation is about 2x as fast as the Rust implementation. Here are my implementations:

```rust
extern { 
    fn array_test(buffer: *mut u8, length: u32);
}

fn main() {
    let mut vectest = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(2 << 20);
    unsafe { // using C function
        vectest.set_len(2 << 20);
        let start = SystemTime::now();
        array_test(vectest.as_mut_ptr(), 2 << 20);
        let end = SystemTime::now();
        println!("C func took {:?}", end.duration_since(start));
    };

    let mut vectest2 = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(2 << 20);
    unsafe { // pure Rust
        vectest2.set_len(2 << 20);
        let start = SystemTime::now();
        let vectest2_ptr = vectest2.as_mut_ptr();
        for i in (0..2 << 20).step_by(4) {
            *(vectest2_ptr.add(i) as *mut u32) = i as u32;
        }
        let end = SystemTime::now();
        println!("Rust took {:?}", end.duration_since(start));
    };
}
```

C function:

```c
void array_test(char *buffer, unsigned int len) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i += 4) {
        (*(int *)(buffer+i)) = i;
    }
}
```

One instance of time results from running `cargo run --release` is:

```
C func took Ok(440.692µs)
Rust took Ok(921.658µs)
```

About every time I run it the C finishes twice as fast.

Is this just due to poor Rust code code optimization on my part? If so, what could I do to close the gap between my C and my Rust?

Comment: Both functions have undefined behavior because the buffer of a `Vec<u8>` is not necessarily aligned properly for an `int`.

Comment: Ouch, you're right. What structure might lend itself more towards holding arbitrary data for serialization, if I wanted `u32`s to go across word boundaries? Not that its a good idea... Right now I'm trying to implement a filesystem for an OS class and decided I might try out Rust instead of just sticking with C.

Comment: FWIW, I couldn't reproduce your results locally; even the original code was faster in Rust by about a ratio of 3:2. Not sure why.

Comment: Re: data structure, you can still cast `*mut u32` to `*mut u8` and have it be properly aligned. You just have to create the buffer as a `Vec<u32>` and then convert it down with `as *mut u8`

Comment: `step_by` has to keep checking whether it's on its first iteration, which makes it far from ideal. Using `for_each` instead of a `for` loop should be faster, since that uses internal iteration so only needs to do that check once.

Comment: I'll give that a try. Thanks @Veedrac!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you re-write your loop:

```rust
for i in (0..2 << 20).step_by(4) {
   *(vectest2_ptr.add(i) as *mut u32) = i as u32;
}
```

as

```rust
let mut i = 0;
while i <= (2 << 20) {
   *(vectest2_ptr.add(i) as *mut u32) = i as u32;
    i += 4;
}
```

the performance difference you're seeing goes away.

From a quick glance at the assembly on [rust.godbolt.org](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/XMGTNg) (using -O as argument for rustc) it looks like rustc/llvm is able to vectorize (with SIMD) the loop when using the `while` variant, but it isn't applying that same optimization to your for loop.

Comment: Indeed, and it seems that Rust runs it faster than my C in that case! That's something interesting to note.

Comment: The numbers seemed pretty close to me (hard to make a statement). If you want to be more certain you'd probably have to (a) do more runs and do a statistical analysis for measurement error. And (b) if you're running this on Linux or another demand-paging OS you're currently highly likely to measure the overhead of the page-fault handler too. Adding a warm-up run will eliminate this problem.

Comment: Yeah, that's true I would have to do an analysis (but not really worth the time). However, even on average after 10,000 iterations, the Rust implementation still seems faster (and it is on Linux, so I added one iteration of each to the beginning for warm-up).